# How Callbacks access Methods

Tags: javascript, express, callback

I am wondering how are we able to use **res.render** inside a callback

```
function getUsers(cb){
  fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    const users = JSON.parse(data);
    return cb(null, users);
  });
}

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  getUsers((err,users) =>{
    if(err){
      res.render('error', {error:err})
    } else{
      res.render('index', {title: "users", users: users.users});
    }
  })
});
```

Because when we pass the callback, Callstack gets loaded up with getUsers(cb) Function, and we are no longer inside the route, then how the callback is using the res.render Method?
And how do I know moving forward, which values is accessible to callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline functions/callbacks like you're using here can see the parent function scope and all of it's variables and arguments.  This is referred to as the "lexical scope".

If the callback was not inline, then it couldn't see those variable/arguments because the function would be declared in a different scope.

So, this is why the inline callback for `readFile()` you've declared can access `cb(...)` and similarly why the inline callback you pass to `getUsers()` can access `req` and `res`.  Those are all arguments in the parent scope.

Note, the access to these parent variables/arguments is not from the call stack.  This is from the [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope).

---

This access to `res.render()` only works because the function is declared inside the lexical scope where `res` is accessible.  If your route was declared like this instead:

```
function getUsersCallback(err, users) {
    if(err){
      res.render('error', {error:err})
    } else{
      res.render('index', {title: "users", users: users.users});
    }
}

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  getUsers(getUsersCallback);
});
```

Then this would not work because the callback function is not declared in a lexical scope which has access to `req` and `res`.

---

Keep in mind that function arguments and local variables in Javascript are stored in scope objects, not on the call stack like they would be in a language like C/C++.  This is for a bunch of reasons, not the least of which is the lifetime of a function scope may extend beyond when the function returns (due to closures) and so that scopes can be chained so the interpreter can lookup things in the parent scope (in order to implement the "lexical scope" that the language implements).